# RHEL6 openssl confusion

Tags: openssl, rhel6

I am trying to update openssl on a rhel6 server. I got it recently from the previous guy who managed this server.

At the start, the following openssl packages were installed:

```
# yum list openssl
Installed Packages
openssl.i686 1.0.0-27.el6
openssl.x86_64 1.0.0-27.el6
```

I notice that the repo configured for packages (different server) has new packages but the rhel6 box doesn't see any new updates.

So I manually copied over recent rpm openssl packages

```
openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.i686.rpm
openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

And removed existing package:

```
# yum remove openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.i686
It removed this version as well as several dependencies.
```

Then tried installing a current version:

```
# yum install openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.i686.rpm  Setting up Install Process Examining openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.i686.rpm:
openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.i686 Marking openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.i686.rpm as
an update to openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64 
Error: Nothing to do
```

So it didn't get installed.

Then I checked current version:

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
```

It appears this 1.0.2a has also been installed earlier, and it has become the current version.

I am a bit confused. How can I verify which openssl version is being used by the system?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

try rpm -qa | grep openssl s an alternative to yum list
then which openssl
and then check the version

[root@localhost~]# rpm -qa | grep openssl
xmlsec1-openssl-1.2.20-4.el6.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64

[root@localhost~]# which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

[root@localhost~]# /usr/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013